# View as Icon in Mac Mail

Tags: macos

I upgraded to High Sierra and now the "View as Icon" option in Mail is no longer there. Is there a workaround?  How do we get this problem fixed?

Comment: What did the "View as Icon" option do? I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the attachment. 
If the attachment displays, the contextual menu will offer "View as Icon." 
If the attachment shows as an icon, the contextual menu will offer "View in place."

Comment: I'm still on macOS Sierra with Mail.app 10.3, and just now noticed that the "View in Place" and "View as Icon" right-click choices are now both missing.